# How to create a java package that lives outside the android project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, package

My android project is called MyPlaces. I want to create a library (package) with commomTools classes that LIVES outside the MyPlaces directory; however, every time I open MyPlaces project and create a new module, Android Studio creates a directory INSIDE MyPlaces called commontools. I want to create this commonTools directory outside, as it is shown in the screenshot and I prefer it not to be an android project.

I just want to be able to import the classes from the package from different Android Applications.

How can I do that?

Thank you for your help.

[image: Screenshot of My Android applications]

Comment: I found it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32579557/how-to-update-an-imported-module-in-android-studio

Answer (score 1):

Create a new project and and a module which is library.

Then you can use jitpack.io to import it from Gradle.

Good luck

Emre

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I was able to import it, by adding a project and add a module as you suggested and then import module and add a dependency in the Module Settings for the app; however, I expected changes on the package classes to be reflected in the project that imports it and that is not the case. Apparently, instead of linking, Android Studio copy the classes in the package into the App Project. It just seems like it defeats the purpose of having a package. Any thoughts? Thanks.