# How to add another project in my existing Android Studio project (do not copy)

Tags: android, reference, multi-module

Create two projects with new-project with Android Studio.

There are two blank projects created above.

I'll name them Project A and B.
A refers to B. A can call a class of B.

If necessary, the two projects must be independently executable by app.
From the beginning, A and B were each made with a new project command.

How can I do this?

The project will be copied, if using the method of adding modules in Project Structure below.

The two projects in Git exist separately. Each is an environment in which a separate developer develops.

I want the project to be only a reference without being copied

If you do the following, an error will occur:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-add-a-library-project-to-android-studio/

[How to use a project in another project as a module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52867963/how-to-use-a-project-in-another-project-as-a-module)

```
[Project A -  settings.gradle]
rootProject.name = "ProjectA"

include (':app', ':projectB')

project(':projectB').projectDir = new File('D:/Development/Android/multiModuleTest/ProjectB')
```

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':projectB')
    ....
    ....
}
```

[error]

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :projectB.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > No matching configuration of project :projectB was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.4.1', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```